# Intermittent SQL Server connection exception that appears to be related to the browser

Tags: c#, sql-server, google-chrome

This is a C# MVC web application using DevExpress typically run in a Chrome browser. The exception is the standard SQL instance not accessible message

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

IIS and SQL are on the same server, and it's only serving 2 or 3 concurrent users.

When this happens to a single user, other users may still be able to connect. Restarting IIS or SQL Server does not resolve the issue. What does seem to resolve it is closing and re-opening Chrome. It does not happen right away and I haven't been able to pin it to a specific page or action.

What is truly bizarre is that when it happens, I can open an Incognito Chrome window and it will work while the main Chrome window does not.

It appears to occur approximate 30 minutes after the first request. I can replicated the problem in Visual Studio, however when it happens no break points are hit, even in Global.asax.cs or Startup.cs.

I do know that it is code related since deploying the previous version does not cause any issues. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this and suggestions on how to debug.

Comment: Do you have a load balance server? I have seen this happen before when somebody forgets to change the config file on the secondary server.

Comment: no, it's a simple server, IIS and SQL on the same machine. Only 2 or 3 concurrent users.

Comment: The odds of this being _caused_ by the web browser are very small indeed.

Comment: Have you used Developer Tools in Chrome to verify whether the working tab and the non-working tab are making the same requests to the web server?

Comment: Yes. it's not different tabs. It has to be a separate browser instance, like Icognito or IE

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, but I'm unsure if this is a bug or feature. It had to do with the AuthenticationProperties I was using at time of login. If I set ExpiresUTC, I would experience this issue.

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authManager = context.Authentication;
authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = model.RememberMe,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(4)
}, identity);
```

When I removed ExpiresUtc the problem goes away. That will probably lead me to my next SO question on how to extend the login period correctly.